# Sharepoint Central Administration not running

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am getting the following error when I try to browse either the Central Administration or the Web Application:-

```
Unable to connect to database.
Check database connection information and make sure the database server
is running
```

In the event log, I have the following error entry:

The description for Event ID ( 27745 ) in Source ( Windows SharePoint Services 3 ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: #50071: Unable to connect to the database SharePoint_AdminContent_a9991124-7852-4cc2-8a15-470a061b7a0d on svrhspuneet.  Check the database connection information and make sure that the database server is running..

Please help me resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: Presumably your database server 'svrhspuneet' is up and running and you can see the database in SQL Management studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Puneet try running the sharepoint configuration wizard again. your problem will get resolved.

Comment: The problem was: My DNS server was not running and it could not resolve "svrhspuneet". The problem is solved. Thanks!!